# How do I join two results with avg()?

Tags: sql

I have two query results:

```
Select avg(salary), department_id 
from employees
Group by department_id
```

and

```
Select d.department_name, e.department_id
From departments d, employees e
Where e.department_id=d.department_id
```

How can I combine the into one result. Dept. ID on first is primary key for both tables

I tried union, creating new tables... Nothing works I need something like this:

```
Dept_id  |  Dept_name  |  avg_salary  |
---------------------------------------
121      |  Management |   324000     |
---------------------------------------
102      |  Tax        |    432555    |
---------------------------------------
Etc
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please be sure to read the FAQ before posting questions. And please check your code before posting it or - better even - *copy and paste your real code*. Trivial syntax errors (like `groub by` instead of `group by` or `departmet_id` instead of `department_id`) can easily be avoided and waste everyone's time.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want `avarage salary` for each department. For that you shoudl use the `JOIN` with `group by`. And `AVG` aggregate to get the average salary for the department.Try this,

```
SELECT 
    d.department_id,
    d.department_name,
    AVG(e.Salary) AS avarageSalary
FROM
   Department d JOIN Employee e
      ON d.department_id= e.department_id
GROUP BY
    d.department_id,d.department_name
```